# Split C++ nested templates

Tags: c++, swig

I try to use my C++ library in Java project via SWIG. But it seems that SWIG can't understand nested templates. So, this is the valid C++ code which I need to use, but SWIG can't build it:

```
template <template <int,template<typename>class,int> class block, int N, template<typename>class BN>
using residual = block<N,BN,1>;
```

I need to split it in something like this:

```
template <typename T> class BN;
template <int,typename BN, int> class block;
template <int N>
using residual = block<N,BN,1>;
```

But this is invalid C++ syntax.

So, how can I split C++ nested templates in the many non-nested templates?

Comment: I'm curious: why are you bothering with a translator like SWIG?  Why not just port your C++ code to Java, or vice versa?  I would think it would be just about as fast,  less of a headache ... and I'd have a LOT more confidence in the resulting code.  I'm definitely curious "Why SWIG"?

Comment: @paulsm4 I need to use my library with some custom dlib's functions in Java. You can check this: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1589

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't mind using another way(I even tried it, as you can see from the link), but I have only [this working sample](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/tree/master/dlib/java) which wraps dlib using SWIG.

Comment: You could introduce some classes/structs, say `block1024_32_1`, where you inherit from `block<1024,32,1>` and wrap those instead. You can do this in your SWIG header. You need to create an ABI anyway.